# In angular js what is meaning of cust as cust.CustomerName for cust in allRecords

Tags: angularjs

Here is the html code used.

What is meaning of `cust as cust.CustomerName for cust in allRecords`? I am not able to understand, as I am new to `angular-js`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerName" name="CustomerName"
       ng-model="customerDto.CustomerName"
       uib-typeahead="cust as cust.CustomerName for cust in allRecords | filter : $viewValue "
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" autocomplete="off"
       ng-keyup="getcustomerlist($event)"
       typeahead-min-length="3"
       typeahead-on-select="onSelectCustomer()" />
```

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerName" name="CustomerName" ng-model="customerDto.CustomerName" uib-typeahead="cust as cust.CustomerName for cust in allRecords | filter : $viewValue " typeahead-select-on-exact="true" autocomplete="off" ng-keyup="getcustomerlist($event)" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-on-select="onSelectCustomer()" />

Comment: Please don't add your code in the comments. Edit your question instead.